# jQuery-validate plugin - reset form field status

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to know if it's possible to reset a field (element) validate status?
In the example below for example if you type a wrong email address, it shows as invalid, but after when you delete what you typed and became empty, and it shows as valid instead of nothing (as the field is not required either). Somehow I want it to reset the valid/invalid status. I couldn't find anything in the documentation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Note: I only want to reset the actual field, not the whole form.

```js
$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      email: true,
      required: false
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

input.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email">
</form>
```

Comment: *"if you type a wrong email address, it shows as invalid, but after when you delete what you typed and became empty, and it shows as valid instead of nothing (as the field is not required either)"* - that's working exactly how it's supposed to work.  If the field is not required, then it's considered valid when it's empty.

Comment: `resetForm()` is [the first result in the documentation search](https://jqueryvalidation.org/?s=reset). If you're looking for something that only resets one field, it does not exist.  If you just want to remove the "valid" validation on a single field, that can be achieved by removing the `valid` class. **It might make a lot more sense to just reset the entire form.**